# Like/dislike functionality in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to achieve likes/dislikes functionality but it's not working. I am newbie for this kind of functionality.

I've added my snippet about what exactly I am trying to do.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
 $scope.technologies = [
                        {name:"C",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"C#",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"Java",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"WAD",likes:0,dislikes:0}
                        ];
 $scope.liketech = function(technology){
  technology.technologies.likes++;
 }
 $scope.Disliketech = function(technology){
  technology.technologies.dislikes++;
 }
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
html{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
body{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color:#333;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  
}
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="25">
<th width="25%">Technologies</th>
<th width="25%">Likes</th>
<th width="25%">Dislikes</th>
<th width="25%">Likes</th>
</tr>
<tr height="25" ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
<td>{{technology.name}}</td>
<td>{{technology.likes}}</td>
<td>{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="liketech(technology);"/><input type="button" value="DisLike" ng-click="Disliketech(technology);"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Try change `technology.technologies.likes++` to `technology.likes++`.. And also for dislikes..

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be like this:

```
$scope.liketech = function(technology){
    technology.likes++;
}
$scope.Disliketech = function(technology){
    technology.dislikes++;
}
```

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27575/)

> You have typo in `ng-rtepeat`. Which should be `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass `$index` to make it working.

```
$scope.liketech = function(index){
    $scope.technologies[index].likes += 1;
}
$scope.Disliketech = function(index){
    $scope.technologies[index].dislikes += 1;
}
```

However, this will be applied on client side only.

You can do the database stuffs by `$http` request in your controller function.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
 $scope.technologies = [
                        {name:"C",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"C#",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"Java",likes:0,dislikes:0},
                        {name:"WAD",likes:0,dislikes:0}
                        ];
 $scope.liketech = function(index){
      $scope.technologies[index].likes += 1;
 }
 $scope.Disliketech = function(index){
      $scope.technologies[index].dislikes += 1;
 }
});
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
html{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
body{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color:#333;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  
}
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="25">
<th width="25%">Technologies</th>
<th width="25%">Likes</th>
<th width="25%">Dislikes</th>
<th width="25%">Likes</th>
</tr>
<tr height="25" ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
<td>{{technology.name}}</td>
<td>{{technology.likes}}</td>
<td>{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
<td>
  <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="liketech($index);"/>
 <input type="button" value="DisLike" ng-click="Disliketech($index);"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.technologies = [{
    name: "C",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "C#",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "Java",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "WAD",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }];
  $scope.liketech = function(index,tech) {
    like= parseInt(tech.likes);
    $scope.technologies[index].likes = ++like;
  }
  $scope.Disliketech = function(index,tech) {
    dislike= parseInt(tech.dislikes);
    $scope.technologies[index].dislikes = ++dislike;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr height="25">
      <th width="25%">Technologies</th>
      <th width="25%">Likes</th>
      <th width="25%">Dislikes</th>
      <th width="25%">Likes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25" ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
      <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
      <td>{{technology.likes}}</td>
      <td>{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="liketech($index,technology);" />
        <input type="button" value="DisLike" ng-click="Disliketech($index,technology);" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.technologies = [{
    name: "C",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "C#",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "Java",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }, {
    name: "WAD",
    likes: 0,
    dislikes: 0
  }];
  $scope.liketech = function(index,tech) {
    like= parseInt(tech.likes);
    $scope.technologies[index].likes = ++like;
  }
  $scope.Disliketech = function(index,tech) {
    dislike= parseInt(tech.dislikes);
    $scope.technologies[index].dislikes = ++dislike;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr height="30">
      <th width="25%">Technologies</th>
      <th width="25%">Likes</th>
      <th width="25%">Dislikes</th>
      <th width="25%">Likes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25" ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
      <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
      <td>{{technology.likes}}</td>
      <td>{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Like" ng-click="liketech($index,technology);" />
        <input type="button" value="DisLike" ng-click="Disliketech($index,technology);" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```